# how to save file along with some data in php

Tags: php

I have html input fields.

Those input fields are

1.name

2.title

3.lyrics

4.upload

Now I need to save name, title, lyrics and upload files into database at same time.How to do this??

Here I share my codes

```
 <?php
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "upload"); // 
     Establishing Connection with Server
   $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "song"); // Selecting Database from 
 Server
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which 
  travels in URL
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $lyrics = $_POST['lyrics'];


   if($name !=''||$title !=''||$lyrics !=''){
   //Insert Query of SQL
   $query = mysqli_query($connection, "insert into users(name, title, 
   lyrics) values ('$name', '$title', '$lyrics')");
   echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
   }
   else{
   echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
   }
   }
   mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
   ?>



   <div style="margin:1em auto; width:333px; text-align:center;">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <table style="margin-top: 200px;line-height: 27px;">
     <tr><td><label for='name' >Name: </label></td>
         <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>   <label for='title' >Title: </label></td>
       <td> <input type="text" name="title"></td></tr>

         <tr><td>  <label for='lyrics' >lyrics: </label></td>
        <td><textarea cols="25" name="lyrics" rows="5"></textarea></td></tr>

         <tr> <td>  <label for='file'>upload:</label></td>
         <td><input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload!" ></td></tr>
       </table>
              <button class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" 
       value="Insert">save</button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

I will save name, title, lyrics data into database.

But when I try to save upload file into database, it shows an error

Comment: You aren't inserting any image into the database in your code?

Comment: what does the error say? your query is trying to insert data which seems to describe a SONG into USERS table. is that your intention?

Comment: What have you tried to remove the error on your own?

Comment: I need to upload songs with song name,title,lyrics at same time.

Comment: I dont know how to save files into database along with name,title,lyrics at same time

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$newname = "newname.".$ext; 

$target = 'images/'.$newname;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive file content is a `$_POST`entry. Files are uploaded in a temporary directory, and you'll have deal wth `$_FILES` array. Check [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) documentation page for more.

Answer (score 0):

To access uploaded files you need to refer to $_FILES.

```
$file = $_FILES['files'];
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']));
```

And then you can save $base64 to a database as you save other fields that come in form. But I strongly discourage you from saving files in a database. Instead, you should consider saving a file in a chosen directory and save only name of the file in the database.